# Super Mario 3D World - Rosalina's Run-in-Circles Spin

Tags: super-mario-3d-world

I just discovered that Rosalina has another spin that can be activated when she runs in circles almost in place (ie: joystick spin for quite a few rounds). However, I haven't yet figured out the purpose of this type of spin. It looks a bit like a helicopter spin that boosts jumping? Or maybe it's also an attack spin, but slower? So... I ask the wisdom of the Internet: what are the uses for this type of spin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That move is known as a [spin jump](https://www.mariowiki.com/Spin_Jump#Super_Mario_3D_World), and it can be performed by any character. Its main advantage is that it slows your descent and jumps a little higher than a normal jump, so you can use it to get to places that would be difficult or impossible with another type of jump.